# Following Jest Docs, Getting an error on mockImplementation(). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm doing my best to follow along with the docs for jest and I'm also trying my best to learn on my own. I'm having an issue while following the docs on the official jest website. I'm on the mocking modules section. It had to do with axios but I kept getting the error in typescript that that mockImplementation is not a property on (whatever the mock is)

I've tried looking around to see if it's an issue with my config but I can't figure it out.

#### foo.ts

```
// foo.ts
export default function() {
    // some implementation;
  };
```

test.ts

```
import foo from '../src/foo';

// test.js
jest.mock('../src/foo'); // this happens automatically with automocking
foo.mockImplementation(() => 42);
foo();
console.log(foo())
```

Here is the error I get on mockImplementatin

```
Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '() => void'.ts(2339)
```

All I'm doing is following the docs. I've had no issue until I got to section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `foo.ts`:

```
export default function() {
  return 1;
};
```

...can be mocked like this:

```
import * as fooModule from '../src/foo';

jest.mock('../src/foo');

const mockedFooModule = fooModule as jest.Mocked<typeof fooModule>;
const foo = mockedFooModule.default;

test('foo', () => {
  foo.mockImplementation(() => 2);
  expect(foo()).toBe(2); // Success!
})
```

The typing for `Jest` provides `jest.Mocked` which can be used to generate the correct typing for an auto-mocked version of a module.

In this case the module has a single `default` export so this line:

```
const foo = mockedFooModule.default
```

...will assign `foo` to the correctly typed mocked default export.

Comment: Thank you for the example! how would I go about mocking axios in the mocking modules section  ? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have questions...Is the solution you've presented specific to typescript itself? I didn't figure this out on my own which makes me question if I know Typescript well enough. Where do you recommend I go to learn this?